# Eliminar registros duplicados en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, delete

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create table personas (
id  number(10), fecha_nac date, nombre  varchar2(20)
);

alter table persona add constraint pk_persona primary key (id);
```

en la cual tengo registros que están repetidos.

Me gustaría eliminar los duplicados por nombre y fecha y quedarme con el de menor id.

Por ahora tengo esto, pero no sé cómo añadir la fecha:

```
DELETE FROM persona 
WHERE nombre IN (SELECT nombre FROM persona GROUP BY nombre HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Muy buena pregunta, no es en absoluto trivial.

Vamos a necesitar que el `id` sea autoincremental:

```
ALTER TABLE persona MODIFY id int AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Empecemos insertando unos datos de muesta:

```
INSERT INTO persona (fecha_nac, nombre) VALUES
  ('2001-05-05','Aitana'),
  ('2001-05-05','Aitana'),
  ('2001-05-05','Eva'),
  ('2001-05-05','Eva');
```

A continuación detectaremos los registros con los que queremos quedarnos:

```
SELECT nombre,fecha_nac,
  MIN(id) id
  FROM persona
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Y el siguiente paso será **marcar** aquellos con los que **NO** queramos quedarnos:

```
UPDATE persona
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT nombre,fecha_nac,
      MIN(id) id
      FROM persona
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(nombre,fecha_nac,id)
  SET persona.nombre=NULL
  WHERE c1.id IS NULL;
```

De forma que únicamente nos quede eliminarlos:

```
DELETE FROM persona
  WHERE nombre IS NULL;
```

Otra opción sería **eliminarlos directamente**, evitando el marcado previo, con:

```
DELETE FROM persona
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
      FROM persona
      GROUP BY nombre,fecha_nac
  );
```

En el dataset que nos pasas llamas a la tabla `personas` en vez de `persona`; y, en tu query, borrarías **todos** los registros duplicados sin quedarte con los de menor `id`.

Para evitar realizar esta operación de limpieza, puedes definir una **clave única** que directamente rechace duplicados:

```
ALTER TABLE persona ADD UNIQUE(nombre,fecha_nac);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Un apunte mientras la id sea única i tenga un orden no hace falta que sea incremental en la tabla si ya lo obtienes en otro lado como en un programa.

Comment: Cierto, aunque, ¿para qué harías externamente algo que ya te hace forma natural el motor de tu base datos?

Comment: Depende en mi caso cuando me paso era debido a que era obtenido de otro motor i se repartia en diferentes tablas el mismo id  aun siendo identificador i unico. Era solo un apunte es un caso raro.

Comment: El DELETE directo me gusta mucho más que ese método con el UPDATE. Pero hay una limitación ridícula en MySQL: no puedes usar la misma tabla directamente en UPDATE/DELETE. Por eso tienes que cambiar `FROM persona` con `FROM (SELECT * FROM persona) p` en tu subconsulta. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1eadc52ff91769950593d04b1dd48ae6

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Qué buen aporte... La había probado en MariaDB y no me había dado este error. Curiosa la forma de soslayarlo, ¡gracias!